# Saving a bitmap to the gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

This is the source code: https://github.com/rchampa/Android-Signature-App

```
private void saveBitmapToGallery(Bitmap bitmap){

    String filename = "firma-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";
    String url = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, filename , "Firma creada desde Signature app");
    showToast(url);
}
```

And I'm seeing this:
[image]

But my gallery(on emulator) is still empty. What's going wrong?

## EDIT

I found the image saved in a directory called Images(¿?) in the root.
But the gallery is still empty.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me on Emulator running Android 8.0. I could see the image in gallery. Just ensure the bitmap generated is valid.

Comment: @Sagar How can I check if a bitmap is valid? is not null, and have a 480*800px measures. I updated the post with the github repo.

Comment: Your git hub is also working fine for me. Just ensure permissions are granted correctly

Comment: Really? I will try a real device.

Comment: yeah. Its working fine. You need to ensure permission is granted correctly. For me it didn't work when permission was not granted.